# Struggling to install pandas_datareader with conda install

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to install pandas_datareader through conda install but having no luck. Each time I get the error message:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::charset-normalizer-2.1.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Euan Ritchie\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Euan Ritchie\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

This is after the following commands run in the Anaconda prompt:

```
anaconda search -t conda pandas_datareader
anaconda show delichon/pandas_datareader
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/delichon pandas_datareader
```

I then do what it suggests (ran `conda clean --packages`), then restarted the prompt, but then got the same error message.

I'd greatly appreciate any help. Conda version is 4.3.30 and python version is 3.6.1.final.0 if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install it properly using:

```
conda create --name <env_name>
```

then:

```
conda activate env_name
```

then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-datareader
```

If the last step doesn't work try updating conda, or installing it with pip.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is okay, but could be improved if it 1) included explanation of why to use `conda-forge` channel instead of random user channel `delichon`; 2) why `pandas-datareader` instead of `pandas_datareader`; 3) recommended specifying requirements at *creation* time instead of creation+activation+install, i.e., `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3.10 pandas-datareader`.